# Is it possible to force invoked default transform operator to start/finish with custom event?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

This is a very simplified version of the addon, I'm working on:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

def get_oa():
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    layer = bpy.context.view_layer
    layer.update()
    oa = bpy.context.active_object
    return oa

def get_basics():
    oa = get_oa()
    def get_ix(oa):
        count = len(oa.data.vertices)
        ix = np.empty(count, dtype=np.int32) # check dtype!!!
        oa.data.vertices.foreach_get("index", ix)
        return ix,count

    def get_sl(oa):
        count = len(oa.data.vertices)
        sl = np.zeros(count, dtype=np.bool)    
        oa.data.vertices.foreach_get("select", sl)
        return sl

    def basics(oa):
        ix,count = get_ix(oa)
        slB = get_sl(oa)
        sl = ix[slB]
        return count,sl

    count,sl = basics(oa)
    return count,sl

def go_right():
    count,sl = get_basics()
    if sl < count - 1:
            sl = np.add(sl, 1)
    else:
        sl = 0
    return count,sl

def slct_trgt(count,sl):

    oa = get_oa()
    setSl = np.zeros(count, dtype=np.bool)
    setSl[sl] = 1

    ## deselect all components first
    setF = np.zeros(len(oa.data.polygons), dtype=np.bool)
    setE = np.zeros(len(oa.data.edges), dtype=np.bool)
    setV = np.zeros(len(oa.data.vertices), dtype=np.bool)
    oa.data.polygons.foreach_set("select", setF.ravel())
    oa.data.edges.foreach_set("select", setE.ravel())
    oa.data.vertices.foreach_set("select", setV.ravel())
    oa.data.update()

    ## select targetVtx
    oa.data.vertices.foreach_set("select", setSl.ravel())
    oa.data.update()

#### Right Arrow 
class rKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    '''right Arrow Key'''
    bl_idname = "view_3d.print_rarrow"
    bl_label = "print right arrow"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        return self.invoke(context, None)    

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print ()
        print ("rightward")

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') ## update selection

        count,sl = go_right()
        slct_trgt(count,sl)

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')    

        bpy.ops.ed.undo_push()
        bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

        return {'FINISHED'}

addon_keymaps = []
wm = bpy.context.window_manager
kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon

def register(wm, kc):
    bpy.utils.register_class(rKey)

    if kc:
        km = kc.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D', region_type='WINDOW') ## Object & Edit Mode both
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new('view_3d.print_rarrow', 'RIGHT_ARROW', 'PRESS', ctrl=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(rKey)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register(wm, kc)
```

This works well so far.
I can step over the verticies and transform every one of them if I wish. What I don't like is the RIGHTCLICK to stop the transform operator for verticies I want to keep in place. Instead, I would like is to start the transform operator only, when needed.

Is it possible to initiate with LEFTMOUSE PRESS and end when LEFTMOUSE RELEASE?

Do I have to create my own transform operator for this? (I am aware of the modal template)
Since I plan to reinvoke different operators from history I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I think this would be a good question if it was formulated well.

Comment: @Martynas Žiemys I try really hard

Comment: @batFINGER I can't see why this would be a better place to ask. Can you explain? Sorry, if I was unable to make myself clear. I hope it is better now.

Comment: Thx! The code should wotk now.